# Reading a file from a different directory in matlab

Tags: matlab, directory

My matlab function is in a folder that contains the main project and the other functions of the code. However, the data is stored in a folder withing the main one named "data" and inside the specific dataset that i want, for example "ded4" in this example. I can't figure out how to open the text file that I want without changing the file to the main folder. The code I have so far is:

```
function[Classify] = Classify(logDir)

%%%%logDir='ded014a04';

Directory = ['data/' logDir '/']
Filename = [logDir '-fixationsOffSet']
File_name = fullfile(Directory,Filename)
File = fopen(File_name,'r')

end
```

[image: The code is in the 'dev' folder]

The code is in the 'dev' folder, I think my path is correct because when I do

```
open(File_name)
```

it opens.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Every time a run the fopen it increases a number to File. First time I ran it was 1 and now it's at 25... It doesn't open the file I need it to

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? Per the documentation, [`fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) returns a *file identifier*, which you use as an input for [other low-level IO functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/low-level-file-i-o.html).

Comment: Oh, so I can't access the file per say just using fopen? I'm thinking that might be the problem then. Thanks for the help, sorry for making this silly question

Comment: Yes, as excaza pointed out you will need to call functions to read the file. `fopen` just opens the file for read (or write).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open the file in the editor, use

```
open(File_name)
```

If you want to read data from the file, you can use

```
dlmread(File_name) % Read ASCII delimited file.
```

or

```
C = textscan(File,'FORMAT') % Read formatted data from text file or string.
```

or more low-level using fscanf, e.g., if the file contains three columns of integers you do the following: Read the values in column order, and transpose to match the appearance of the file: (from the help of fprintf)

```
    fid = fopen('count.dat');
    A = fscanf(fid,'%d',[3,inf])';
    fclose(fid);
```